# SFINAE on Error in Dependent Type causes unexpected hard error

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

I have code that I can simplify down to something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct dependent
{
    using type = typename T::type;
};

template <typename T>
typename dependent<T>::type
foo(const T& x);

bool foo(bool x) { return x; }

int main()
{
    foo(true);
}
```

This fails to compile with g++ 9.3 with `--std=c++17` with the error:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct dependent<bool>':
test.cpp:11:1:   required by substitution of 'template<class T> typename dependent<T>::type foo(const T&) [with T = bool]'
test.cpp:17:13:   required from here
test.cpp:6:11: error: 'bool' is not a class, struct, or union type
    6 |     using type = typename T::type;
      |           ^~~~
```

This is not what I would expect. I would expect that attempting to substitute `bool` for `T` in `template <typename T> typename dependent<T>::type foo(const T& x)` would be a failure, which is not an error. It seems SFINAE is not working for me, but I do not know why.

From the examples in the unofficial reference on [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

> Substitution proceeds in lexical order and stops when a failure is encountered.
>
> ```
> template <typename A>
> struct B { using type = typename A::type; };
>
> template <
>   class T,
>   class   = typename T::type,      // SFINAE failure if T has no member type
>   class U = typename B<T>::type    // hard error if T has no member type
>                                    // (guaranteed to not occur as of C++14)
> > void foo (int);
> ```

I am hitting the case on `class U = typename B<T>::type`, but the "guaranteed to not occur as of C++14" bit seems to indicate that this should not be happening as of C++14. What gives?

Comment: That example is meant to illustrate _proceeds in lexical order and stops when a failure is encountered_. Because substitution into the first default template argument fails, the second default template argument is not substituted into at all.

Comment: The example is a demonstration of the workaround I was looking for, but I couldn't understand that by looking at it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is that `dependent<T>` **has** `type`, but that one might be ill formed causing hard failure.

You might make `dependent` SFINAE friendly:

```
template <typename T, typename Enabler = void>
struct dependent
{
};

template <typename T>
struct dependent<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>>
{
    using type = typename T::type;
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8348441fca50a85e)

Comment: Even simpler: `template<class T, class  = typename T::type> struct dependent {};`?

Comment: Can you explain how it would be ill-formed causing a hard error? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) states that "attempting to use a type that is not a class or enumeration on the left of a scope resolution operator `::`" causes an SFINAE error.

Comment: @bipll: I prefer the void version, it is more generic. as it allows additional specializations (as `std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>>`).

Comment: @alterigel: Read the *"Substitution occurs in"* part, so `dependent<T>::type` is indeed a substitution, but `using type = typename T::type;` is not, it is a side-effect of `dependent<T>` instantiation, and *"errors in those side-effects are treated as hard errors"*.